# Criteria for duplicate site proposal

Tags: discussion, questions, area-51, site-proposal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request for arguments/considerations on site proposal rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86192/request-for-arguments-considerations-on-site-proposal-rejection)

What are the criteria for designating a site proposal as duplicate?

Why, for instance, are the sites 'Poker' and 'Game of Go' not designated as a duplicate of 'Board and Card Games', while other games recently were?